# How do I fix the tiny font in my Windows 7 system dialog boxes?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

Something happened today which caused all system dialog boxes to change the font they use to something that is almost unreadable.  The link below is a snip from the *System Properties* dialog which shows the small text:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGW2b.jpg]

Note that the window title is readable.

The *Window Color and Appearance* dialog does not allow me to change it.  I can change the theme to "Basic" or any other built-in theme and it still displays incorrectly.  I have another user account on this computer and that user account behaves the same way.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the answer given on [this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/small-font-problem-in-some-system-windows/297f42d8-8bb8-42ec-8b68-f3ddda3005f2) - it should solve your problem.

Check the values `MS Shell Dlg` and `MS Shell Dlg 2` the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
```

On my machine, the values are:

- `MS Shell Dlg` has the value of `Microsoft Sans Serif`,
- `MS Shell Dlg 2` has the value of 'Tahoma'.

Expanding on the purpose of these keys:  They allow applications to avoid hard-coding font names for use in dialogs; the system fonts to be changed as necessary to support non-English character sets.

Comment: Changes the font, but not the size?

Comment: At the same font size, some fonts are smaller; MS UI Gothic, for example, at 8 points is smaller than MS Sans Serif at 8 points. MoolBoran is tiny at that size.

Comment: The above keys (MS Shell Dlg and MS Shell Dlg 2) were the same on my system.  I found that the Tahoma font was missing (could not select it as a font in any app).  I re-installed the Tahoma font but that still did not fix the dialog.  I ran ProcessMonitor and saw that the process was accessing the 'MS Shell Dlg' registry key so I changed that from Microsoft Sans Serif to Tahoma.  Now the original dialog is readable.  There are still places where the text is unreadable (Notepad++ for example).  I suspect that whatever 'Microsoft Sans Serif' ultimately refers to is also missing.

Comment: Notepad++ was using 'Courier New' which was also missing.  Re-installed the font and now Notepad++ looks fine.  I will just have to look for missing fonts as I find them.  Thank you for pointing me down the correct path, Geoff.

Answer (score 8):

Go to `Control Panel -> Personalization -> Window Color -> Advanced appearance settings`.

[image]

Go through each item in the `Item` drop-down and see if anything has a very low `Size` set in the Font section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but everything in there looks fine.

Comment: My reg keys were the same as listed in the answer but the personalization settings worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mike, Download and install Tahoma font from following link
http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Tahoma/
It will solve your problem.
Nebo

Answer (score 0):

Access other computer, go to Control Panel> Font, copy all fonts and paste them to your computer at the same path. Every font is ok. Sure!

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting. Are you 100% this is a clear answer with clear instruction and that's it's appropriately applicable for an answer?