# Change default windows dialog font without dpi scaling

Tags: windows, fonts, appearance

In Windows, there is the "Window Color and Appearance" dialog. There you can change: title, message box, menu, status bar,icon fonts... However you cannot change the **default window font**.

It is always "Tahoma" 8.25

I can change its face by changing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes\"MS Shell Dlg 2" value:
as a result I have "Tahoma", 14

But it does not change the size. - how can I change 8.25 to something higher, to make the font legible?

Just out of curiosity, is there any plausible reason for Microsoft not allowing to change it?

If I change dpi scaling it will change the rendering size of all fonts without changing the size. It also causes some applications to have controls outside the window boundary.

What I would like to do is to set default windows dialog font to "Segoe UI", 14 (just like I can change messagebox font).

This question was already asked on:
[answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-desktop/how-can-i-change-default-windows-dialog-font/d4675f8a-c064-49a4-b28b-57dd802fe652) but never answered

Also on: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/425449/how-do-i-fix-the-tiny-font-in-my-windows-7-system-dialog-boxes) a kind of similar question was asked, but no usable answer about the font size was given.

Here a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dQqy.jpg) of what font size I would like to change:

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Windows7, but this question also applies to WinXP, WinVista, Win8 and Win10.

Answer (score 0):

Change the values of:
"MS Shell Dlg 2"="Tahoma"
"MS Shell Dlg"="Microsoft Sans Serif"
To a bigger font like ; KacstBook (normal ), Noto Sans Lao (big), Noto Kufi Arabic (very big).
Example

"MS Shell Dlg 2"="Noto Sans Lao"
"MS Shell Dlg"="Noto Sans Lao"

That will make it more readable.