# Windows 10 Upgrade - Windows Dialogue Boxes Have Small Font

Tags: windows-10

My laptop has recently been rebuilt with Windows 10.  It was previously also using Windows 10.

Now the default Windows dialogue boxes that popup have a smaller font that is less well defined.   Nothing has changed in the hardware.

File explorer looks the same.  But the popup dialogue box that I get if I right click on a file and select 'Properties' for example has smaller font.

Can I fix this?

Comment: right click on your desktop and click Display Settings, Check the size of text, apps and other items...change it from 100 % to 125% ?

Comment: Thanks @Elmo.   I have tried that.   It is too much.   I just want a small font improvement in the core windows dialogues.

Comment: Is your problem same as in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/425449/how-do-i-fix-the-tiny-font-in-my-windows-7-system-dialog-boxes)?

Comment: It does appear to be @harrymc.   However, the funny thing is that the problem has fixed itself without me taking any action other than perhaps a restart.   Place your comment as the answer if you like.

Comment: I can't, since this then becomes a duplicate, so I'll mark it as duplicate.